# Does the ODBC Driver libpsqlodbcw for PostgreSQL support updateable cursors?

Tags: postgresql, odbc, psqlodbc

I am running PostgreSQL Version 9.3.4 on an Ubuntu 64 bit Server.

I am using the PoatgreSQL ODBC Driver (libpsqlodbcw) version 9.03 on HP-UX.

I am able to connect, retrieve data and do general sequel updates.  However, when I attempt to update a cursor with `SQLSetPOS`, I get the error:

```
Only SQL_POSITION/REFRESH is supported for PGA PI_SetPos
```

I have attempted using the syntax `select * from table for update of table` (and many versions of this) and nothing has worked.

I am guessing, at this point, that such updates are not supported. Does any one have any input on this?

Comment: The server certainly supports updateable cursors. Whether psqlODBC does is a separate thing - try asking a new question specifically regarding psqlODBC, **showing your code**.

Answer (score 1):

YES, cursor can update.

```
digoal=# begin;
BEGIN
digoal=# declare cur cursor for select * from t;
DECLARE CURSOR
digoal=# fetch next from cur;
 id | phone | cnt 
----+-------+-----
  1 |     1 |   3
(1 row)

digoal=# update t set cnt=1000 where current of cur returning *;
 id | phone | cnt  
----+-------+------
  1 |     1 | 1000
(1 row)

UPDATE 1
digoal=# select * from t where id=1;
 id | phone | cnt  
----+-------+------
  1 |     1 | 1000
(1 row)

digoal=# end;
COMMIT
digoal=# select * from t where id=1;
 id | phone | cnt  
----+-------+------
  1 |     1 | 1000
(1 row)
```